# Compiling LAME for QNX

Tags: cross-compiling, qnx, lame

I'm trying to compile LAME to work on a QNX host. I've tried running the following commands.

```
$ ./configure --host=i386-pc-qnx
$ make
```

As you can see, it produces a 64-bit ELF file which obviously won't work on 32-bit hardware. (I also tried running it just to make sure.)

```
$ file lame
lame: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=, not stripped
```

This [link](http://lame.sourceforge.net/download.php) says LAME can be compiled for QNX, and I get no errors when I run the configure script, so I know `i386-pc-qnx` is a valid host name.

This is my first time cross-compiling a program, so it's quite possible I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of QNX are you using?

Comment: QNX 6. I ended up just copying the output from make (basically just a bunch of gcc invocations) and putting it in a bash script. Then I used search and replace to modify the commands to use the QNX toolchain. It's pretty hacky but it works.

Comment: It's good that it worked!

Comment: can you please put the solution as an answer and mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just copying the output from make (basically just a bunch of gcc invocations) and putting it in a bash script. Then I used search and replace to modify the commands to use the QNX toolchain. It's pretty hacky but it works.